# How do I install Arduino drivers?

Tags: arduino-uno, windows

I need to install my Arduino drivers, but Windows 8.1 doesn't seem to like Arduino, and it greys out the update driver button. Therefore I can't select the drivers from the drivers folder in my Arduino IDE folder.

There are drivers that need to be installed. But Windows 8.1 greys out the `update driver software` button. Also, it refers to Arduino Uno as an `unknown device`. How do I install the Arduino drivers and make Windows let me install the drivers?

Comment: Are the drivers signed?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Try right-clicking on the .inf file and selecting "install".

Comment: Have you tried following the Windows 8 instructions at https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-arduino-ide/windows ?

Comment: Have you tried following the Windows 8 instructions at http://dawdevel.blogspot.com/2012/12/arduino-uno-on-windows-8-without.html ?

Comment: Which .inf file Majenko?

Comment: What Arduino is it?  Is it a genuine one, a clone or a fake? Where did you get the drivers from?  Do you know what version they are?  Are they on CD/DVD or downloaded?

Comment: I've fixed the problem now :). The drivers needed administrator rights for modification and I'm not admin so I asked my admin to allow me to update the drivers

Answer (score 1):

The IDE package usually ships with the driver(at-least the latest one). 
Go to **Program Files** in **C:** and find the **Arduino** folder and you should find a folder named **Drivers**. Inside you will find an application named **dpinst-x86**. Run it and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Often reinstall the latest arduino IDE with Windows Administrator rights helps (use right click execute as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

If the arduino is undetected in PC go to control panel-device manager - connect the arduino and some COM port will appear click it and troubleshoot make sure your PC is connected to internet and then you will be able to see your com port in arduino ide.